# Consuming Web Service via Windows Authentication

Tags: web-services

I am just trying to consuming a web service in remote computer using windows authentication however login credentials are different in local & remote computer.

Code Snippet:

```
Dim objproxy As New WebReference.Service1
'Create a new instance of CredentialCache.
Dim mycredentialCache As CredentialCache = New CredentialCache()
'Create a new instance of NetworkCredential using the client
Dim credentials As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential("username", "pwd","domain")
'Add the NetworkCredential to the CredentialCache.
'mycredentialCache.Add(New Uri(objproxy.Url), "Basic", credentials)
objproxy.Credentials = credentials
```

It is timing out but when i use

```
mycredentialCache.Add(New Uri(objproxy.Url), "Basic", credentials)
```

I get "401 Unauthorized" message,

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

You want windows authentication so use:

```
mycredentialCache.Add(New Uri(objproxy.Url), "Negotiate", credentials)
```

See [Passing Credentials for Authentication to Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302390.aspx#secnetch10_passingcredentialsforauth)

Comment: Tuzo, Thanks for the link i have tried using the above option it doesn't work :-(

Comment: Can you browse the service using a web browser?  Also you can try inspecting the HTTP traffic using something like Fiddler to see what is happening on the wire.

Comment: Tuzo, I am able to add webreference successfully,have to check with fiddler to find out what's wrong with it